# Sudden problem with first three frets, especially the high E string

Tags: acoustic-guitar, strings, semi-acoustic-guitar

I bought a new semi-acoustic guitar 8 months ago and it sounded absolute wonderful up until a week ago. I am experiencing that the high E string, and to a lesser degree the nearby B and G string, sounds horrendously when pressed and played on the first three frets. Making playing a D chord sound terrifying.

I've uploaded a small youtube video here, where you can see and hear what I am talking about.

I'm thinking that it might be that the string is digging into the nut and therefore is closer to the frets, but I am no expert. Unfortunately the store I bought it from went bankrupt, so I cannot ask them.

Added a image here for extra good measures:
[image]

What is your take on this.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first suggestion doesn’t work and your guitar has a truss rod, loosening the truss rod a 1/4 or 1/2 turn will probably do the trick. You can confirm this by holding down a string at the 1st and last fret. There should be a small space, about 1 mm or 1/16” between the string and the frets halfway up the neck. This is called relief, a slight concave bowing of the neck and all string instruments need to have some. When the weather starts to change, instruments, especially acoustic instruments can need some adjusting

Your thought about the string digging into the nut is unlikely because in that case the open string would also buzz.

Answer (score 3):

Grab a steel rule & set it edgewise on the fretboard between the E & B strings.

My guess is it will rock over the 3rd or 4th fret. One is high, it's popped slightly.

You can reset it by laying a piece of wood over the fret, rest the neck firmly against a surface that won't put strain on the headstock or body joint as you do it & gently tap the fret back down with a hammer [hitting the wood, not the fret]

A good picture, as clear as your existing one, of the edge of the fretboard around that area might also show a visible gap, for confirmation; or you may actually be able to feel the sharp edge if you run a finger over it [carefully, they can be razor sharp.]

BTW, if it will not reseat, or soon pops back up again, then you need a luthier.